# Symfony 3 theme integration

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.2

I want to integrate custom theme for my Symfony 3.xxx application and I'm unable to find an appropriate link that how to do this, is there any tutorial?

Actually, I have two separate views:

```
  1. frontend for public
  2. backend for admin purpose.
```

the frontend has different theme and backend has the different theme.

Please suggest me a better solution, I think for backend I can create separate Admin Bundle and it has its own css, js etc but I'm not sure about `base.html.twig:` can I create new base.html.twig file for Admin bundle?

I have seen Symfony demo application structure and following it but I have doubt maybe it's wrong.
I put all my css, js, images and other files under web dir.

```
web
 -audio
 -css
 -font
 -img
 -js
 -video
```

base.html.twig:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/animate.css') }}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/font-awesome.css') }}">
     ....
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}

    <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
     ...
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Here is a live project that uses symfony if you want more than just the tutorials offered by symfony documentation. Symfony docs do point out best practices using their frame work. https://github.com/EnMarche/en-marche.fr

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another base, or just extend from it and create 2 main templates one for backend and one for front-end using {% extends %}

I wouldn't recommend creating a separate bundle for Admin area unless you're thinking about reusing it into another application.

As for where to store your assets, here is the Symfony best-practice:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html